# how to merge this array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

This is my first array `var_dump`

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(55) {
    ["Primary Maths"]=>
    NULL
    ["Primary Environment"]=>
    NULL
    ["Primary English"]=>
    NULL
    ["Primary Sinhala"]=>..........etc
```

**In first array contain 55 array elements.**.

This is my second array `var_dump`

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(660) {
    ["Primary_MathsJAN"]=>
    string(7) "checked"
    ["Primary_MathsFEB"]=>
    string(7) "checked"
    ["Primary_MathsMAR"]=>
    string(7) "checked" ...etc
```

**In first array contain 660 array elements.**.

So i want to merge(JOIN)  first array with second array.But i want it like this.I want to join first array one value with second array 12 values...

```
1st array elements(55) * 12 = 2nd array elements(660)
```

Is there anyway to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will split the 2nd array into an multidimentional array into 12 element chunks, and combine it with the first array. However, it looks like you need to use the keys from the 1st array, so I added the function array_keys:

```
array_combine(array_keys($a1), array_chunk($a2, 12))
```

Comment: try array_combine(array_keys($a1), array_chunk($a2[0], 12)) - it looks like your second array has an array inside it

Comment: Warning:  array_combine() [function.array-combine]: Both parameters should have an equal number of elements in /home/itstec2/public_html/vista/paysearch.php on line 115

Comment: well $a1 has to have the same number of elements that $a2/12. Apparently $a1 doesn't have 55 elements or $a2 doesn't have 660 elements.

Comment: can we make a new array from array 2 where contain 12 values and 55 array index

Comment: if you want $a2 to have 12 values with 55-element arrays, then use array_chunk($a2[0], 55). Note that the [0] is only here, because when I look at your array above I see you have the 660-element array as a first element of another array.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some combination of built in functions you could use, but every time I find myself in a situation like this I'd rather just write 2 loops and be done with it. In case you decide to follow my example what you can do is foreach the first array and then use a regular for with 12 loops for the second array within the foreach. You might also want to use array_values on the second array in order to save yourself the trouble of fighting keys.

Best wishes and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If I have well understand the question, this will do the job:

```
$result = $array1[0];
$temp = array_chunk($array2[0],12);
foreach ($result as &$value) {
    $value = array_shift($temp)
}
```